# Is it possible to create tablespace in existing datafile in Oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

Now I have created 1 tablespace named work_schema and datafile named schema.dat.
And I need to create one more tablespace called assign_schema and I would like to use same schema.dat file. Is this possible?

Comment: Seems to be more of a question for a DBA than a developer.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, due to the way Oracle Logical Storage Structures work ([see the Oracle Concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/logical.htm#CNCPT301)), there is no way of using the same datafile for two tablespaces. Each tablespace has to have its own datafile(s).